# Add new user and usermeta into database with SQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I've using this to create a new user in the WordPress database...

```
// Add user to WP users table.
$user_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "users";
$unique_string = substr(md5(rand(0, 1000000)), 0, 10);
$wpdb->insert( $user_table_name, array( 
    'user_login'        => sanitize_text_field($_POST['email']),
    'user_pass'         => sanitize_text_field(MD5($unique_string)),
    'user_email'        => sanitize_text_field($_POST['email']),
    'user_registered'   => sanitize_text_field(date("Y-n-d G:i:s")),
    'user_status'       => $_POST['1'],
    'display_name'      => sanitize_text_field($_POST['first_name']) . " " . sanitize_text_field($_POST['last_name'])
) );
```

...which works fine, and let's pretend that the **ID** of that user turned out to be **1234** in the database table (thanks to auto increment).

So now I also need to add the corresponding user meta information into the **usermeta** table for that user, and this is where I get a little confused.

The code above is easy because it's just adding a row to a table. But the usermeta table is different because it will need - in this case - a bunch of rows with the corresponding **user_ID** of **1234** each respectively with:

- nickname (I'll use the email address for this)
- wp_capabilities (value to be **a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";b:1;}**)
- sales (a custom field I have - value will be set to the word "**yes**")
- colour (another custom field I have - value will be set to the word "**green**")

I'm guessing the SQL statement is going to be similar to the one at the start of this post.

If anyone could show me, that would be awesome.

**UPDATE:**

So this is mostly done. This works:

```
// Add corresponding user metadata to WP users table.
$usermeta_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "usermeta";
$last_id = $wpdb->insert_id;
$role = sanitize_text_field('a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";b:1;}');

$wpdb->query( 
$wpdb->prepare( 
    "
     INSERT INTO $usermeta_table_name (
         `umeta_id`, 
         `user_id`,
         `meta_key`, 
         `meta_value` ) 
     VALUES (
         NULL,
         $last_id, 
         $usermeta_table_name . 'capabilities',
         '$role' )
    ",
        $last_id, $last_id 
    )
);
```

That will add one row to the **usermeta** table, but how can I add 2 more rows within the same statement?

Answer (score 0):

Store the last inserted row's ID to a variable:

```
$last_id = $wpdb->insert_id;
```

now, use this `$last_id` variable for metadata insertion. The [`insert_id`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class#Class%5FVariables) variable is provided by the wpdb class.

Comment: How would the query look then? I though this would work (http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_row) but that only seems to allow for 2 columns on a row, whereas I need 3 columns in the row (user_ID, meta_key and meta_value) - and I need 3 rows worth.

Are you able to show me an example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it helps, see my update in the original post. I've included a solution for adding a single row, but I don't know how to add two more within the same statement. Thanks!

Comment: @user3256143 It'd help a lot if you provide actual data to be inserted, into which tables, and with what values. I can not make assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I feel a little silly about this - though to be fair it's been a long time since I wrote any SQL :-)

The answer is simply to follow this method:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```